# Пример Android приложения на Delphi XE - БД изображений и способы ее передачи на ПК

Tags: delphi, sqlite3, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe5, android-sqlite

Помогите с примерами на Delphi XE5-8.
Система будет состоять из 2-х частей: приложение на Андроид - дневник, где пользователь делает записи, приклепляет фото c камеры или галереи.
Приблизительно раз в неделю пользователь будет подключать планшет к ПК и по нажатию кнопки сливать накопленный материал (фотографий 100-300)

Вопросы:

1) Есть ли пример такого приложения на Андроид: 
блокнот с возможностью прикрепления изображений. Как это делать примерно понятно, но рабочий пример бы сильно помог.

2) Перекачивать данные на ПК. Есть ли пример приложения на Андроиде(передатчик), которое закачивает/копирует Базу с изображениями в приложение на Windows(приемник), или другой пример массовой перекачки фотографий по App tethering например.

Comment: Раз вы нашли упоминание про AppTethering (что уже неплохо), можете посмотреть примеры с ним, которые входят в комплект поставки Delphi. Уточнение 1: xe5 не будет работать с последними версиями Android, лучше перейти на RAD Seattle. Уточнение 2: AppTethering не работает через интернет. Оба приложения должны находиться в одной сети. Минусы вам сыпятся из-за отсутствия конкретики: "я попробовал вот так (кусок кода), не получается вот это. Как мне обойти сей недостаток?".

Comment: @kami Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Раз вы нашли упоминание про `AppTethering` (что уже неплохо), можете посмотреть примеры с ним, которые входят в комплект поставки Delphi. Наиболее полезным в вашем случае будет пример `PhotoWall` (если установка RAD Studio проводилась с путями по умолчанию, то он находится в папке `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\Samples\Object Pascal\RTL\Tethering\PhotoWall`), где как раз пересылаются фотографии.

Какие компоненты нужно задействовать для "дневника" - зависит от дизайна приложения. В простейшем случае - это список из `TMemo` и нескольких `TImage`, добавляемых динамически. Более сложный, но возможно более красивый - использовать RichEdit. На текущий момент бесплатных версий такого компонента для FMX пока не существует. На сайте [fire-monkey.ru](http://fire-monkey.ru/) Ярослав Бровин только готовит свой компонент к релизу. Из платных стоит посмотреть в сторону [TMS FMX Pack](http://tmssoftware.com/site/tmsfmxpack.asp).

Уточнение 1: RAD XE5 не будет работать с последними версиями Android, лучше перейти на RAD Seattle.

Уточнение 2: AppTethering не работает через интернет. Оба приложения должны находиться в одной сети.

Минусы вам сыпятся из-за отсутствия конкретики: "я попробовал вот так (кусок кода), не получается вот это. Как мне обойти сей недостаток?

Comment: kami, большое спасибо вам за помощь! Мобильную часть я сделал   очень помогли исходники небезвестного Андрея Ефимова. Теперь все-таки вопрос, как базу и картинки с Андроида перекинуть на ПК - какой то проверенный пример работающий на последних версиях Андроида (Если не касаться AppTethering - тут примеров хватает)

Comment: @Maxx Что вы подразумеваете под "перекидыванием"? Это обмен информацией между двумя приложениями (одно на компьютере, другое на мобильном устройстве) или же приложение только на мобильном устройстве, а компьютер "просто есть" ? Если первое - ничего лучше `AppTethering` не найдете. Если компьютер представляет собой *сервер_в_интернете* - смотрите примеры с http (`Indy` и `System.Net`). Если второе - то ищите, как передавать данные в **расшаренную** папку по smb (вроде так)

Comment: Ок, спасибо за инфо! Будем искать.